# Strange behaviour observed while SMPS testing:

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I was doing [load regulation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_regulation) for the converter [NB679GD](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/NB679/document_id/4030). The converter supports input voltage from 5.5 V to 28V and produces a regulated output of 5V. Load is varied from 0.01A to 8A.

The test was performed for three different input voltages- 6V, 7.5V and 8.5V. For 6V input, the output voltage increases initially ( ofcourse within regulation limits) but decreases at higher loads ( above 5.5A). Whereas for 7.5V and 8.5V inputs, output voltage increases monotonously as loading increases.

Why is the trend different for low input voltage? Is there a theory behind this or a random occurrence?

Comment: No theory; probably just your test setup and equipment.

Comment: Can you quantify this change? Is this within the load/line specifications?

Comment: For low input voltage (6V), it goes out of regulation limits at higher loading.        At 7A loadin o/p dips to 4.4V.